# I am not able connect jsp with sql server using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

Here is my code

Insert title here

I am getting like this errors

HTTP Status 500 -

---

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:541)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:850)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:779)
    org.apache.jsp.userlogin_jsp._jspService(userlogin_jsp.java:96)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.userlogin_jsp._jspService(userlogin_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.14 logs.

---

Apache Tomcat/6.0.14

Comment: hi, have you added the jar file ( jtds-1.2.5.jar) to build path?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up on your build the JTDS driver lib.